# How to read stream data from jdbc with flink streamtable api

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I found there are only DDL and yaml format configuration in the section of jdbc connector,I don't know the way to use them.so I am asking for how to read stream data from a jdbc data source when writing a flink app jar.if it can be,does the stream get updated if data has changed in the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Support for ingesting CDC streams from JDBC databases is coming in Flink 1.11. See [FLIP-105](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=147427289). This will do what you're asking for, including updating the stream as the underlying database tables are changed.

For examples of what's already possible in Flink 1.10, see the [Flink SQL Demo](https://github.com/fhueske/flink-sql-demo) shown in [this talk from Flink Forward](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnCkwIp_614) by Timo Walther and Fabian Hueske. For example, in Flink 1.10, you can join a stream with a lookup table in MySQL. In the demo (linked to above) this is done by using a Hive catalog to describe some MySQL tables, and then this query

```sql
SELECT
  l_proctime AS `querytime`,
  l_orderkey AS `order`,
  l_linenumber AS `linenumber`,
  l_currency AS `currency`,
  rs_rate AS `cur_rate`, 
  (l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) / rs_rate AS `open_in_euro`
FROM prod_lineitem
JOIN hive.`default`.prod_rates FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF l_proctime ON rs_symbol = l_currency
WHERE
  l_linestatus = 'O';
```

is used to compute euro-normalized amounts using the current exchange rates stored in MySQL.

Comment: thank you, but I got confused with streamtableenvironment api. the 'registetable"/"registertableSource" methods are deprecated so I can't use the "JdbcTableSource" in the flink-jdbc jar or write a custom lookup table source. And not like kafka or hbase, there's only ddl and yml configuration in the flink doc. so I don't know how to config a jdbc stream table with java/scala.

Comment: The registertable methods have been deprecated, but they will work. I would just use them for now until the new interfaces in 1.11 are available.

Comment: You might want to start with 1.11 now, in fact. flink-1.11.0-rc3 is available for testing, and is a big step forward in this area.